# react native: r3f-native-orbitcontrols: android vs chrome vs firefox and use also for several canvases?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, orbitcontrols

I want to render several models and each shall have its own canvas and orbitcontrols. I made that work by the following code, but I make two observation:

1. clicking first time on a model doesnt initiate the rotation and looking into the source code of r3f somehow it trys to detect the first touch and only regard everything afterwards as rotation control.
2. when keeping the finger on the display of my android (i run via expo) and leaving the current canvas the target camera position resets somehow to a weird position that i can make visible within the handleCameraChange function via console.logs. This does not happen when testing rotation outside of the canvas in a browser (firefox or chrome). Is that behavior on android intentional? Is related to the fact that DOM is handled differently for web and android?

```
import React, { Suspense, useRef, useMemo, useContext, useCallback, useEffect, useState, lazy } from 'react';
import Chair from './src/components/chair';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber/native';
import useControls from 'r3f-native-orbitcontrols';
import * as THREE from "three";
import Trigger from './src/components/Trigger';
import Loader from './src/components/Loader';
import { useVisibleStore } from './src/context/MyZustand';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';


const Game: React.FC = () => {
  const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
  const isPortrait = height > width;
  const nCubes= useVisibleStore((state) => state.nCubes)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const controlsAndEvents = Array.from({ length: nCubes }, (_, index) => {
    const [OrbitControls, events] = useControls();
    return { OrbitControls, events, index };
  });

return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.modelsContainer}>
        {loading && <Loader />}
          <View style={isPortrait ? styles.columnContainer : styles.rowContainer}>
            {controlsAndEvents.map(({ OrbitControls, events, index }) => (
              <View key={index} style={isPortrait ? styles.modelColumn : styles.modelRow}{...events}>
                  <Canvas key={index}>
                    <OrbitControls
                      key={index} 
                      enabled={true}
                      enableZoom={false}
                      enablePan={false}
                      dampingFactor={0.5}
                      enableRotate={true}
                      rotateSpeed={0.5} 
                      // onChange={(event) => handleCameraChange(event, index, letters)} 
                      {...OrbitControls}
                    />
                    <directionalLight position={[1, -1, -1]} intensity={5} args={["yellow", 10]}  />
                    <directionalLight position={[-1, -1, -1]} intensity={7} args={["white", 10]}  />
                    <Suspense fallback={<Trigger setLoading={setLoading} />}>
                      <Chair />
                    </Suspense>
                  </Canvas>
              </View> 
             ))}
          </View>
         </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'grey', // Add this line to set the background color to grey
  },
  modelsContainer: {
    flex: 0.9,
  },
   columnContainer: {
    // flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
  },
  rowContainer: {
    // flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
  },
  modelColumn: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  modelRow: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default Game;
```